# why state is not changing when changing the line of the setstate

Tags: reactjs

please need your help,
when changing the following line `setloadingstate(prevState => prevState = false)` to be inside the arrow function inside promise will work fine but when remaining as following, it doesn't work fine and state remains false, any explanation?

```
const IngredientsHandler=(ingredients)=>{
    setloadingstate(prevState => prevState = true)
    fetch('https://ingredients.firebaseio.com/ig.json',{
        method:'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify(ingredients),
        headers:{
            ContentType:'application/json'
        }
    }).then(response => {

        return response.json()
        },
    )
        .then(
        responseData => {
            setIngredientsState((prevState) => ([...prevState,{id:responseData.name,...ingredients}]))

        },

        setloadingstate(prevState => prevState = false)
    )

}
```

Comment: Is `setloadingstate()` a hook? You can just write `setloadingstate(false)`. You're returning an assignment to `prevState` which I don't think makes sense.

Comment: first, yes it is a hook `const [loadingstate,setloadingstate]= useState(false)` 
second, I don't know when should I use the prevstate when changing it or not as you state

Comment: please I need your help, if you have any questions to clarify sth, just ask

Comment: Use `prevState` when you need to access the current value. Like `prevState => prevState + 1` (increase the current state by one) or `prevState => !prevState` (false to true or true to false). https://react-hooks-cheatsheet.com/usestate

Comment: thanks or sharing with me the link, regarding my main question any help with it

Comment: `setloadingstate(prevState => prevState = false)` will be executed before the request receives data. Maybe try `async await` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're using `prevState = true` within `setloadingstate` when you aren't even using `prevState` value. Try this

```
const IngredientsHandler=(ingredients)=>{
    setloadingstate(true);
    fetch('https://ingredients.firebaseio.com/ig.json',{
        method:'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify(ingredients),
        headers:{
            ContentType:'application/json'
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(responseData => {
        setIngredientsState((prevState) => ([...prevState,{id:responseData.name,...ingredients}]));
    }).finally(() => {
        setloadingstate(false);
    });
}
```

`async` / `await` is cleaner

```
const IngredientsHandler= async (ingredients)=>{
    setloadingstate(true);
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://ingredients.firebaseio.com/ig.json',{
            method:'POST',
            body:JSON.stringify(ingredients),
            headers:{ ContentType:'application/json'}
        });
        const responseData = await response.json();
        setIngredientsState((prevState) => ([...prevState,{id:responseData.name,...ingredients}]));
    } catch(ex) {
        console.error({ ex }); // handle error(s)
    } finally {
        setloadingstate(false);
    };
}
```

Comment: the top example does not work in this case, as the `then` does not return the promise. The `setIngredieentsState` should go to another `then`, and then the `finally`. I would prefer the `async/await` version for sure. Just note that `response.json()` returns a promise.As @Flupper has used it correctly.

Comment: @Julian Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: @SILENT, Thanks for your answer, I prefer the first solution it worked for me, but for my code when I tried to debug the `loadingstate` remains false although I turned it true at the beginning of the Handler, do you have any clues ?! :D

Comment: @Flupper react refreshes constantly. It holds updates until a refresh is called. If a function is ran quickly, then the value doesn't have enough time to get updated. You could update it faster by calling `setloadingstate(() => true);` but its unnecessary in most situations.